# Is it okay to show the offer letter to my current employer?

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, job-offer, job-change

I have just received an offer from Company B while working in Company A. The offered salary from Company B is about 1.5 times better than my current Company A. After telling my boss from Company A for resignation, he is keen to keep me by counter offering a better pay. But he demanded some proof of offer. As a proof, I have my letter of offer from Company B with all the benefit details and their human resource department contacts. While I don't mind disclosing my benefits to my current employer, I am not sure if my current employer will contact Company B (will they?) to check and ask about the offer in detail. If that happens, will that be appropriate? How will my new employer think?

Comment: Your question suggests that were A to make a counteroffer that matches B's offer, you might accept. Is this correct?

Comment: @AakashM I won't accept the counter offer unless it is significantly better than what B's offering. But I think it is fair to give them a chance since they are very keen to keep me.

Comment: You are too far apart.  Go with the answer from Romski.

Comment: I don't see any need to show him the letter and I'd be a little suspicious of the request. Why should he need proof? He's either willing to pay you so much or he's not.

Comment: Never accept a counter offer. It is only setting you up to burn a bridge while giving your current company time and leisure to replace you.

Comment: To add on to what others have said: I hope you didn't tell company A the name of company B. Who knows what petty stuff they might pull between HR departments.

Comment: If there was an "Amen, brother!" button on WorkPlace, I would click it twice for @JoelEtherton's comment.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is my opinion, but I would not show your current employer the letter for the following reasons:

- It may compromise your position at the other company
- Why do they need the letter to determine your worth

I would also be wary of any counter offer because:

- Why were you so grossly underpaid in the first place
- What will their opinion be of you if you stay (e.g. how they view your loyalty, would they pass you over for promotion, etc.)
- They may be keeping you because it is cheaper/more convenient than hiring someone new
- You may burn your bridges with the other company, especially if they have given you what you asked for, or more.
- All the reasons that made you look for a new job in the first place are still valid.

I spent some time in a recruitment company and my experieince is that those who accept a counter offer usually end up moving later anyway.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

After seeing @Romski's excellent answer, if you still **absolutely** want to show the offer letter to your current employer, I would suggest you to show them a partial copy of the offer letter.

You can put the letter to a scanner, erase the benefits details and other irrelevant parts, such as human resource department contacts, etc, on the scanned copy. I would even suggest you to erase company B's name to protect yourself and company B. Then show that partial copy which has the salary offer.

Please note that I agree with what Romski says. In particular, *Why do they need the letter to determine your worth?*